# Assignment and scheduling problem with resource constraints

Tags: scheduling, assignment-problem, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I have 10 tasks with 6 workers. Each worker can only serve one task at a time and must complete the task before moving on to the next task. Each worker has a maximum work output value and each task has an amount of work required. A worker can output work at any continuous value up to its maximum work output for any given minute. Each task (in units) need not begin at it's start time (in mins), but must be completed by its max_completion_time (in mins). We are trying to minimize overall workload across all workers at any given time.

Maximum work output:

```
Worker 1: {'max_work_output': 10 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
Worker 2: {'max_work_output': 10 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
Worker 3: {'max_work_output': 10 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
Worker 4: {'max_work_output': 10 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
Worker 5: {'max_work_output': 10 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
Worker 6: {'max_work_output': 50 units per min, 'ramp_up': 5}
```

Task work units needed, minimum start time, and maximum completion time:

```
Task 1:  {'work_needed': 3000 units, 'min_start_time': 0, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 2:  {'work_needed': 3600 units, 'min_start_time': 0, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 3:  {'work_needed': 1800 units, 'min_start_time': 5, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 4:  {'work_needed': 1200 units, 'min_start_time': 10, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 5:  {'work_needed': 3300 units, 'min_start_time': 15, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 6:  {'work_needed': 3000 units, 'min_start_time': 20, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 7:  {'work_needed': 3600 units, 'min_start_time': 30, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 8:  {'work_needed': 1800 units, 'min_start_time': 100, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 9:  {'work_needed': 1200 units, 'min_start_time': 100, 'max_completion_time': 600}
Task 10: {'work_needed': 3300 units, 'min_start_time': 120, 'max_completion_time': 600}
```

- when a worker changes it's output this can only be done at a maximum value of `ramp_up`.
  Objective:
  What is the optimal schedule (which includes the work output at each minute from each worker) that minimizes the maximum sum of work across each worker?
- The solution should be a 10 x 6 x 600 tensor that describes each worker's output at each minute for each task - where we minimize the sum of any matrix along the $T$ dimension

Wondering if there are any other examples of similar work or how this solution would be formalized/implemented.

Comment: What limits a worker from always working with maximum output ?

Comment: @Kuifje If all workers worked with max output simultaneously it would drive up the max sum of work - which the objective is trying to minimize

Comment: Can a task be done by multiple workers ?

Comment: @Kuifje No, once a task is assigned to a worker it must be completed by that worker alone. And the worker can not work on multiple tasks at once

Comment: Can workers start on t=0 to work on something or will they need to ramp up or uptime_delay first?
Why would you shut down a worker can't they just run idle?

Comment: @worldsmithhelper yes, a worker can start at t=0. Yes, I suppose you are right - a worker can simply run idle - I'll edit my question. I guess I was trying to limit the amount of times the worker goes to 0 and then back to working again.

Comment: Why do you want to minimize the worst case, most unequal schedule and not just find a minimally unfair schedule?
To do that we could $\min c$ where c is an upper bound to the sum of work of each worker.

Comment: In general i am extremely confused about what your objective means. To help clearify the dimension of all your objects, what indices mean what, over what indices you minimize and maximize.


My current interpretation of your objective doesn't make sense. You minimize the result of a maximization of a vector which is produced by summing all work units time sheets over the worker$\times$machine combinations.


The problem is you can't minimize a vector here, you can only minimize scalar things, such as an vector being indexed.

Comment: @worldsmithhelper hopefully the second explanation of the tensor helps. I want to minimize the max sum of all work at any time step. The sum should result in a scalar for every time step and is summing an nxm matrix at each time step - then take the max of this vector. That’s what I want to minimize.

Comment: @worldsmithhelper hmm, ok yes $\min c$ makes sense to me. I thought initially you meant to simply upper bound the sum of work across all workers at any time step, but if we are minimizing this upper bound and it is not simply a scalar value - I think this makes sense. Is $c$ the upper limit of the sum of all workers' work or the upper limit of each individual worker's work? Because I really care about the sum. Imagine I have to pay these workers simply based on that max value I mention in the other comment.

Comment: So do i understand it correctly that you want to minimize the peak working speed of the most unit per time producing worker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123830/discussion-between-worldsmithhelper-and-jchaykow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a way to express the transition constraints so i give a description what this does and mention what it lacks.

```
using JuMP
using Gurobi #needs Gurobi license but any other MILP solver callable from JuMP should work too## Heading ##
using UnicodePlots
```

are dependencies. I used UnicodePlots for debugging. It is neat. In Julia dependencies can be installed via `]add JuMP` in the Julia shell. Gurobi also needs to be installed and have a license. Another solver like should also do the trick. Learn more [here](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/installation/#Installing-a-solver) .

```
workers = [
  10 5;
  10 5;
  10 5;
  10 5;
  10 5;
  50 5;
]

tasks = [
  3000 1 600; #out of bounds if 0
  3600 1 600;
  1800 1 600;
  1200 10 600;
  3300 15 600;
  3000 20 600;
  3600 30 600;
  1800 100 600;
  1200 100 600;
  3300 120 600;
]

sim_time = 600; #needs to be bigger or equal than the last time stamp
```

Is the problem information you provided. It could have also been stored in structures, dictionaries but i went with arrays for simplicity

```
model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)

@variable(model, workspeed[1:(size(workers)[1]), 1:(size(tasks)[1]), 1:sim_time], lower_bound = 0)

for i=1:(size(workers)[1])
  @constraint(model, workspeed[i,:,:] .<= workers[i,1])
end
```

Since worker top speed differs there is no good way to define all upper bound at once. Here i broadcast the lesser or equal constraint over all `workspeed` of an particular worker.

```
@variable(model,p)
@constraint(model,sum(workspeed,dims=(1,2)).<=p)  #the sum over all dimensions expect time, the total work at each time point
```

This define the objective which is the lowest maximum over all work happening at any time point.

```
@variable(model, work_done[1:(size(tasks)[1]), 1:sim_time], lower_bound = 0)

for i=1:(size(tasks)[1])
  for j=1:tasks[i,2]
    @constraint(model, work_done[i,j] == 0)
  end
  for j=(tasks[i,3]):sim_time
    @constraint(model, work_done[i,j] >= tasks[i,1])
  end
end

for t=1:(sim_time-1)
  @constraint(model, work_done[:,t+1] .==  work_done[:,t] .+ sum(workspeed,dims=1)[1,:,t])
end
```

This block could be almost removed and i think Gurobi does that during presolve sometimes. `sum([ workspeed[:,i,t] for t=(tasks[i,2]):(tasks[i,3])]) >= tasks[i,1]` or something similar could do the trick and eliminate the necessity for `work_done` completely. This block makes sure that work on tasks is not started early or finishes late.

```
for t=1:(sim_time-1)
  for w=1:(size(workers)[1])
    @constraint(model, -workers[w,2] .<= workspeed[w,:,t+1] .- workspeed[w,:,t] .<= workers[w,2] ) # different ramp down?
  end
end
```

constrains the growth/decline of the all individual workspeeds. In the previous version i had constrained the sum instead which allowed the solver to keep production speed when switching tasks. Now that this constraint is enforced properly, switching can still happen for free and instantly when production speed is <= the wind_up without down time.

```
@variable(model, workson[1:(size(workers)[1]), 1:(size(tasks)[1]), 1:sim_time], Bin)
@variable(model, worksonatall[1:(size(workers)[1]), 1:(size(tasks)[1])], Bin)
```

These binary variables are responsible for enforcing the scheduling logic. If a worker `n` ever works task `t` `value(worksonatall[n,t])` will be true. While forcing certain values to false can be used to forbid people from working on something, it would be more smart to not generate the backbone in `workspeed` and other places. While presolve might remove it would be better not to generate it at all.

Note that without this logic a linear program would result which could be solved a lot faster.

```
for i=1:(size(workers)[1])
  @constraint(model, workspeed[i,:,:] .<= workers[i,1] * workson[i,:,:] )
end
```

This ensures that if a worker works on some task at some time that this information is available as a boolean.

```
@constraint(model, sim_time*worksonatall[:,:] .>= sum(workson,dims=3)[:,:,1]) # any
@constraint(model, sum(workson,dims=3)[:,:,1] .>= worksonatall[:,:]) # any
```

This code established the relationship between `workson` and `worksonatall` the latter is the logical or over all time of `workson`.

```
@constraint(model, sum(worksonatall, dims=1)[1,:] .== 1)
```

Every task can only ever be worked on by one worker.

```
for t=1:sim_time
      for w=1:(size(workers)[1])
      @constraint(model,sum(workson[w,:,t]) <= 1)
    end
end
```

A worker can work at most at one task at a time.

```
@objective(model, Min, p)

optimize!(model)

println(value.(worksonatall))
```

Defines objective and hands problem to the solver.
Show which worker work on what which is useful for debugging.

I let the program run over night on my quadcore. Gurobi found an global optimum. The resulting array of workspeed is pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/A6PGtFSL).
Here is an excerpt of the log for every time a new incumbent integer solution was found:

```
    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time


* 2465  1985             731      43.7307033   43.07179  1.51%   421 1356s
H 2649   930                      43.4719711   43.07179  0.92%   402 1884s
H 2877   601                      43.2761578   43.07179  0.47%   422 1983s
H 2879   571                      43.2646048   43.07179  0.45%   422 2321s
H 2879   543                      43.2423208   43.07179  0.39%   422 2321s
H 2880   516                      43.2367973   43.07179  0.38%   422 2762s
H 2888   495                      43.2312925   43.07179  0.37%   421 6594s
H 2956   566                      43.2282794   43.07179  0.36%  1065 13263s
H 2978   535                      43.2033898   43.07179  0.30%  1141 13263s
H 3006   683                      43.1895093   43.07179  0.27%  1165 15293s
H 3340  1119                      43.1725888   43.07179  0.23%  1567 16752s
H 3489  1048                      43.1587838   43.07179  0.20%  1591 16752s
H 4936  1195                      43.1418919   43.07179  0.16%  1459 18634s
H 4963  1148                      43.1165541   43.07179  0.10%  1461 19244s
H 9711   972                      43.1008403   43.07179  0.07%  1470 27005s
H11482   430                      43.0904523   43.07179  0.04%  1498 29415s
H12431   220                      43.0717863   43.07179  0.00%  1513 31324s
```

The resulting objective is 43.071786310517524.

**workspeed by workers over time**
[image]

**workspeed on tasks over time**
[image]
We see that the tasks in the current formulation can get resumed later. The easiest way to achieve no resumes would be to constrain the sum of xors between successive workson to be 2 and to set initial workspeed to 0 for all workers, alternatively or with some amount related to the sum of workson could work to. At the moment worker 6 starts with the maximal work speed. This would almost double the amount of binary values though and make the search space less relaxed. [See here how to do or and xor](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/02/xor-as-linear-inequalities.html). However i think there should be a better solution.

**work_done on tasks over time**
[image]

**sum of workspeed over time**
[image: sum of workspeed]

Comment: This is fascinating. So how do you interpret the output `p` of the model `println("p: ---> ", value.(p))`? Is this the maximum `p` or is it the `p` value of the last time step?

Comment: The solver Gurobi returns an assignment, which gets stored in variables created in the model. You can get the value stored by applying `value` to variable. In case the variables are in an container you need to broadcast the `value` to all elements in the container which is what the `.` is a shorthand for. `p` is the objective, so it is the smallest maximum over all sums of workspeed at any time point.

Comment: So the only thing this does not capture is that once a worker starts a task they must complete that task before moving on to a new task, correct?

Comment: This and it doesn't capture the rest. Currently switching between task like this [5,0] -> [0,5] is legal to.

Comment: @jchaykow Did that work for you and help you?

The  concerns i expressed about problem size probably still apply and the search space can be reduceed a lot if not all can work on all tasks.

Comment: Yes, this is super interesting. The runtime really isn't that bad either. I'm just digging further into this sum of xor question. I'm also thinking about ways of discouraging task switching midway instead of strictly prohibiting it

Comment: You could penalize the sum of time steps someone worked on something slightly, as that discourages stopping and restarting as that takes more time units. That would require no new variables. Are you still working with my Julia code or did you transcribe it into another language?